# Toggle Element width using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have hamburger and menu on the left side, which has `width: 0px;`

How can I do after click on hamburger menu changes width to `250px`, and second click change width to `0px`?

```
var hamburger = $('.hamburger-menu__list').css('width');

$('.hamburger-toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    if (hamburger == '0' ) {
        $('.hamburger-menu__list').css('width', 250);
    } 
    else {
        $('.hamburger-menu__list').css('width', 0);
    };
});
```

Comment: Take a look at [jQueryToggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If it's just open or close the menu, then the `toggleClass` is enough in itself, just set the width in your CSS, with different widths depending on whether the `open` class is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the width every time you click on the button, also you need to parseInt the width to get a right number, `css('width')` returns the value with prefix `px` e.g `250px` so parseInt will remove the prefix and returns pure number, Try this:

```
$('.hamburger-toggle').click(function(){
    var hamburgerWidth = parseInt($('.hamburger-menu__list').css('width'));

    $(this).toggleClass('open');

    if (hamburgerWidth === 0) {
        $('.hamburger-menu__list').css('width', 250);
    }  else {
        $('.hamburger-menu__list').css('width', 0);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work. You have to check hamburger width everytime.

```
$('.hamburger-toggle').click(function(){
    var hamburger = $('.hamburger-menu__list').css('width');
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    if (hamburger == '0' ) {
        $('.hamburger-menu__list').css('width', 250);
    } 
    else {
        $('.hamburger-menu__list').css('width', 0);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still cache `element` but access width every time `click` is invoked.

Another suggestion is to use `ternary-operator` as this is ideal use case to use it.

```js
var hamburger = $('.hamburger-menu__list');

$('.hamburger-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
  var hamburgerWidth = hamburger.css('width');
  $('.hamburger-menu__list').css('width', hamburgerWidth == '0' ? 250 : 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var
    $hamburger = $('.hamburger-menu__list').css('width'),
    $hamburgerToggle = $('.hamburger-toggle'),
    isOpen = false;

function toggleMenu() {
    isOpen = !isOpen;
    $hamburgerToggle.toggleClass('open', isOpen);
    $hamburger.width(isOpen ? 250 : 0);
}

$hamburgerToggle.click(toggleMenu);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You are doing DOM manipulation. It is bad practice to relay on this, because it is asynchronous. A state variable (`isOpen`) helps to have only one source for the state (single source of truth).